# How to create a folder using OneDrive SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, onedrive

For the life of me I cannot find out how to create a folder or list all folders using the OneDrive SDK. Note please this is using the SDK NOT Api. Can someone please show me how to do this?

My aim is to allow users to upload files to a custom directory using a onedrive app using the onedrive SDK

Answer (score 2):

As much as I know SDK uses the same API in the box. Anyway you can try the following way:

```
var folderToCreate = new Item { Name = folderName, Folder = new Folder() };
var newFolder = await client.Drive.Items[parentId].Children.Request().AddAsync(folderToCreate);
```

https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/issues/24
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/docs/items.md#create-a-folder